# General concerns with cookies and privacy

Tags: cookies, user-tracking

The following post is in regards to headless *nix machines only...

I know programs like wget allow options to control cookies. However if a program is not HTTP centric, has little or no options for controlling HTTP, though still makes HTTP requests...
Am I in some way subject to cookie storage then?
If not why? and if so how?

What are all other, if any, methods that servers use to track clients, regardless of the protocol being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie management is the responsibility of the application. When it doesn't support cookies, it won't store any and it won't deliver any. When it does support cookies, it will usually use its own private cookie storage and not share the cookies with other applications. But there is no guarantee that it does not. Refer to the documentation of your programs for details.

The most simple way to track clients regardless of their protocol is of course their IP address. IP addresses are not very reliable because many users can share IP addresses through NAT and when the machine uses a consumer-grade internet connection with DHCP, the IP can change at any time. Servers in proper datacenters, however, often have static IP addresses with a DNS entry, making them easy to trace by their IP address.

Comment: Just to be sure, what you say about IPs is specific to IPv4?

Comment: @BryanK The same applies to IPv6. It is even worse when privacy extensions are disabled, because in that case the MAC address is part of the IP address. But even when they are enabled, the host usually receives addresses which always have the same network prefix, making it possible to identify it.